# for loop through multiple items based on a dataframe

Tags: python, loops, xlsxwriter

So I have several dataframes of different widths.

I want a for loop that will perform an operation on each dataframe's columns:

Table 1:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hi | 1 | Jake |
| Bye | 2 | Mike |
| Red | Blue | Pink |

Table 2:

| cl1 | cl2 | cl3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | Toy | Hello | Present |
| Bike | Ride | Blue | Mike |
| Red | Blue | Pink | Fred |

These tables are in the form a list of tuples.

I want to take these two loops an effectively just have one loop that takes the number of header as the number of items to loop through.

```
 row = 1
 col = 0

 for col1, col2, col3 in (table):
     worksheet.write(row, col, col1)
     worksheet.write(row, col + 1, col2)
     worksheet.write(row, col + 2, col3)
     row += 1
```

```
 row = 1
 col = 0

 for cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4 in (table):
     worksheet.write(row, col, cl1)
     worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cl2)
     worksheet.write(row, col + 2, cl3)
     worksheet.write(row, col + 2, cl3)
     row += 1
```

Here's what I want

iterate through each column in the table no matter the number of columns. What I think it would look like

```
row = 1
col = 0

elements = table.column.names
for elements in (table):
    for i in elements:
        worksheet.write(row, col, i)
        col = col +1
    row = row +1
```

Comment: I want to apply character level formatting to excel. xlsxwriter takes a tuple and applies it, but I need to define the elements like the original examples show, but I just want the statement to adapt to different tables shapes.

Comment: My example data is in the question the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = book.add_worksheet("sheet1")
shape = df2.shape
for col in range(shape[1]):
    for row in range(shape[0]):
        worksheet.write(row, col, df2.iloc[row, col])
book.close()
```

what generate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you DON'T have any dataframes in your code. In python DataFrames are a specific container type provided in the pandas module. And while you don't have any here, you probably should as they are more useful than lists of tuples. Secondly, if I understand you correctly, you want the ability to loop through any table you provide and perform the same actions. This is what functions/methods are for. Declare a function that you then call with each table as a parameter. Assuming your tables are dataframes:

```
def write_to_sheet(table):
    for row in table.index:
        for column in table:
            r = list(tables.index).index(row)
            c = list(tables.columns).index(column)
            worksheet.write(r, c, table.loc[row][column])

write_to_sheet(table1)
write_to_sheet(table2)
```

You will of course need to import your data into pandas dataframes but that is a subject for another question (which you will of course research before asking here as it has been asked many times before).